# unsupported namespace annox xjc maven 1

Tags: maven, jaxb2, annox

I need the XmlRootElement defined in my generated class.  But, getting this error:

```
    [jaxb] [ERROR] [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
```

Here is my binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd http://annox.dev.java.net "
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"  version="2.1">

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../target/src/schema/xmlSchema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='ReportSubmission']">
<annox:annotate>
<annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
name="ReportSubmission"/>
</annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I'm using Maven 1 and a plugin which has an ant task.  Extensions are set to true in the plugin.properties.  I very similar schema is used in another application that uses Maven 2, so I'm thinking the schema is correct and the error message is a little misleading.  Maybe I'm missing a jar ?  The jars I'm using are:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <properties/>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <properties/>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas appreciate, thanks in adv.